# How to find AGDK GameTextInput package in CMakeLists?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, androidx, android-gameactivity

I'm trying to [follow the instructions here](https://developer.android.com/games/agdk/add-support-for-text-input) for integrating GameTextInput from the AGDK (Android Game Development Kit), but am having trouble with the CMakeLists part.

Adding this line as instructed:

```
find_package(game-text-input REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

Results in this error when the project syncs.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "game-text-input"
with any of the following names:
```

There are no names printed. Above is the ONLY output.

I don't know what filename it's looking for, nor where it's looking. Do I need to manually install something or is it supposed to automatically work?

Comment: "I don't know what filename it's looking for" - The format of searched names is actually described in [documentation for find_package command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). Since you are specifying CONFIG keyword, the searched files have format `<lowercasePackageName>-config.cmake` and `<PackageName>Config.cmake`. That results in files `game-text-input-config.cmake` and `game-text-inputConfig.cmake`.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder where that file is supposed to exist? Within the Android SDK?

Comment: I am not aware about GameTextInput, but normally every CMake configuration file should come with the package **installation**.

Answer (score 0):

probably something is missed. Try with the steps in the instruction:

1. enable prefab in your build
   *) in gradle.properties, ensure the followings are there:

   ```
    android.enableJetifier=true
    android.useAndroidX=true
    # optional: pick the latest prefab version at https://github.com/google/prefab/releases/
    android.prefabVersion=2.0.0
   ```

   *) enable prefab in you module gradle file(app/build.gradle)

   ```
     android {
         buildFeatures {
            prefab true
         }
         ...
     }
   ```

   - add the [the latest game-text-input](https://d.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/games) into the dependencies in the same app/build.gradle file:

     ```
         implementation "androidx.games:games-text-input:1.1.2-alpha01"
     ```
2. C++ source code & static lib releases are packed inside the AAR's module include directory. Add them into your build system, for CMakeLists.txt:

   ```
       find_package(game-text-input REQUIRED CONFIG)
       target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
           # other libs
           game-text-input::game-text-input
           android log)
   ```
3. Do a build with Android Studio and it should go through. Then double check a couple of related places in terminal(you can map to windows' locations):

   ```
    cd $your-project-dir/app/.cxx
    find .  | grep game-text-inputConfig.cmake
    # open one of the found cmake config files to observe, no need to change
    cd ~/.gradle/caches
    find .  | grep game-text-input
    # go to the directory find out above, and observe the contents, might be in:
    # ~/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3b2fce467ba34a9f9822795f41da04ae/transformed/jetified-games-text-input-1.1.2-alpha01/prefab
    # you can see the source file release and also the static lib release modules there.
   ```
4. Follow [the instructions](https://d.android.com/games/agdk/add-support-for-text-input) to integrate C++ source files to your project.